# Why does overloaded function template order matter for fundamental types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, overloading

For illustration purposes, say I have this contrived container:

```
template <typename T>
struct Container {
    T v;
};
```

And this contrived "value:"

```
struct Value {};
```

I have a recursive templated function declared exactly like so:

```
template <typename T>
void visit(const Container<T> &c) {
    visit(c.v);
}

template <typename T>
void visit(const T &v) {}
```

With the above, it is perfectly valid to invoke `visit(Value{})`. I can also invoke:

```
void this_works_too(Container<Value> c) {
    visit(c);
}
```

This is a little puzzling, because the recursive call `visit(c.v)` occurs before its definition.

But, when we try the following, we get an error (both from clang 6 and gcc 8):

```
void this_blows_up(Container<int> c) {
    visit(c);
}
```

It complains about the recursive call `visit(c.v)` now:

```
error: call to function 'visit' that is neither visible in the
       template definition nor found by argument dependent lookup
```

However, if we reorder the declarations of `visit`:

```
template <typename T>
void visit(const T &c) {}

template <typename T>
void visit(const Container<T> &c) {
    visit(c.v);
}
```

Both, `this_works_too` and `this_blows_up` compile, successfully.

(This behavior also happens for STL containers and is irrespective of the `const` and reference qualifiers)

Why does the order become important for specializing `visit(Container<int>)` when it wasn't for `visit(Container<Value>)`?

In my research, I had a suspicion that this had to deal with [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (which I admit I do not fully understand). But my best interpretation of this is, at the end of searching in the case of `Container<int>`, the set should have found `int` due to ordinary [unqualified lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup). So, both `Container<int>` and `Container<Value>` should work.

[Godbolt demonstrating this](https://godbolt.org/g/QFnRKN)

I have confirmed that despite the reordering, the correct overload is called (ie. when `visit(T)` is first, `visit(Container<T>)` is actually invoked for `visit(Container<int>)` instead of just choosing the more generic `visit(T)`). I believe this is because the most specific specialization is chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my research, I had a suspicion that this had to deal with ADL (which I admit I do not fully understand).

You're right that this is the problem.

> But my best interpretation of this is, at the end of searching in the case of `Container<int>`, the set should have found `int` due to ordinary unqualified lookup.

Ordinary unqualified lookup cannot see the `template <typename T> void visit(const T &v)` overload because it hasn't been declared yet. Argument-dependent lookup is an exception to that; it can see all declarations at the point of instantiation.

The type `int` is a built-in type not related to any particular namespace. Because `int` does not have any associated namespaces, there are no namespaces in which ADL searches for declarations, so there is no way for the second declaration to be found.

The type `Value` is a user-defined type in the global namespace. Because of that, ADL searches in the global namespace for declarations, and in that case, it does find the second declaration.

Comment: Indeed, if you place `Value` in a namespace, you get the exact same compilation error: https://godbolt.org/g/BeShHV

Comment: Intersting! Thanks for explaining this. The page I linked to was way to convoluted for me to ever derive such a clear and concise explanation as yours! Just to be clear, the point of instantiation here is the invocation of the function, correct? (which is why you can't put all the declarations below their usage?) Is there any reason why it works this way? Does this enable some behavior that would otherwise be impossible? This seems very counterintuitive.

Comment: @BaileyParker With function templates, it was clear that something allowing later declarations to be seen was needed, but allowing that in the general case is problematic. I think it's sort of a balancing act, it needs to be useful enough for the programmers to use, but not so complex that compiler vendors couldn't reasonably implement it.